# How to mock interface properly in Mockery?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mockery

For a unit test, I create a mock object via:

```
$passenger = M::mock(PassengerInterface::class);
```

I pass this mock into a service I want to unit test. That service is trying to access a method, which is not defined, and hence failed as expected via:

```
[BadMethodCallException] Method Mockery_3_Dreamlines_BookingService_Bundle_Bundle_Entity_PassengerInterface::isInfant() does not exist on this mock object
```

I thereby defined the method on the mock object via

```
$passenger = M::mock(PassengerInterface::class)->shouldReceive('isInfant')->andReturn(false);
```

Yet this fails the test unexpectedly via:

```
[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Argument 2 passed to Dreamlines\BookingService\Bundle\Bundle\Operator\ResponseModifier\InfantPriceModifier::adjustPrice()
must implement interface Dreamlines\BookingService\OperatorBundle\Entity\PassengerInterface,
Mockery\CompositeExpectation given
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the fluent syntax incorrectly.

Mockery's `andReturn` does not return the mock object, but the expectation. You should rather create an instance, mutate that, and then use the modified intance:

```
$passenger = M::mock(PassengerInterface::class); // creates the mock
$passenger->shouldReceive("isInfant")->andReturn(false); // this returns an expectation, let's ignore that return value
// now you can use $passenger as expected
```